# Support for an interactive form with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, form

I just failed in a JavaScript test and I would really appreciate some comments of how I can improve so I can keep learning.

The test was about making a form interactive, where the code should do things like changing to the next tab while showing not visible content, validate email, etc.

I have received the following feedback to consider:

`[-]` caching (no jquery selector is cached)----
`[-]` performance optimization (nope, usage of jquery each instead of a native loop)---
`[-]` reusable code (hardly, as commented above)---
`[+]` clean code and good structure---

`[ ]` Extra points for applied design pattern

---

```
$("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />").insertAfter("[type='text/css']");   // CSS de Jquery UI

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};


function setTabOn(stepNumber) {
    stepNumber = parseInt(stepNumber);
    $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").addClass("on");
    $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").click(function() {
        $(".step").hide();
        $("#step" + stepNumber).show();
        $("#steps a.active").removeClass("active");
    }); 
}

function nextStep(stepNumber) {
    stepNumber = parseInt(stepNumber) + 1;
    $(".step").hide();
    $("ol#steps li a").removeClass("active");
    $("#step" + stepNumber).show();
    $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").addClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".back").click(function() {
        var idBack = $(this).attr("id");
        var idBack = idBack.match(/\d/) - 1;
        $(".step").hide();
        $("#step" + idBack).show(); 
    });

    $("#step2_confirm_button").click(function() {
        $("#step2_confirm").dialog("destroy");
        nextStep(2);
        setTabOn(2);
    });

    $("#step2_cancel_button").click(function() {
        $("#step2_confirm").dialog("destroy");
    });

    $(".step").hide();
    $("#step1").show();
    $("#step1_tab").addClass("active");
    $("#step2_confirm").hide();

    $("#step1_next").click(function() { 

            var flagFirstStepError = 0;
            var flagFirstStepEmpty = 0;
            var flagFirstStepEmail = 0;

            $("#step1_errors").html("");

            $(".required").each(function() {    
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    flagFirstStepError = 1;
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    flagFirstStepEmpty = 1;
                }

            }); // end each                                                      

            if (flagFirstStepError == 1) {
                $("#step1_errors").append("We are sorry, but you need to enter all the required fields in order to proceed. The following information is missing: <br /><ol>");
                $(".required").each(function() {                                                             
                    if ($(this).val() == "") {
                         var labelId = $(this).attr("id");
                         var y = $("#step1 label[for=" + labelId + "]").html();
                         $("#step1_errors").append("<li>You must fill the " + y + " field</li>");
                    }
                }); // end each
                $("#step1_errors").append("</ol>");
            }

        var userEmail = $("#email").val();
        if (!isValidEmailAddress(userEmail)) {
                $("#step1_errors").append("<p> You must provide a valid email adress");
                flagFirstStepEmail = 0;
        }
        else {
            flagFirstStepEmail = 1;
        }

        if (flagFirstStepEmail + flagFirstStepEmail == 2) {
            nextStep(1);
            setTabOn(1);
        }

    });  //end click                                                         


        $("#step2_next").click(function() { 
                $("#confirm_list li").remove();
                $("#share_list li label").find("input:checked").each(function() {   
                    var x = $(this).val();                                                                                                          
                    $("#confirm_list").append("<li>" + x + "</li>");
                });

            $("#step2_confirm").dialog();

        });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initial notes

- **[-] caching (no jquery selector is cached)**

  You should be creating variables that store the elements you're selecting with jQuery. The reason for this is that when you call `$("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab")` for example, jQuery will determine what type of selector it is (id), and them call `document.getElementById("step" + stepNumber + "_tab")`. This is particularly important when you're selecting multiple elements.
- **[-] performance optimization (nope, usage of jquery each instead of a native loop)**

  So you used `$.each`, what is the problem with that? Well it is doing a tonne of other stuff just so you can have some nice convenient syntax. For systems you're trying to optimise you should probably stay away from it, prefer this:

  ```
  var required = $(".required");
  for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
      // object is required[i]
  }
  ```

  As you can see from [this jsPeft](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/148), a native `for` loop is much faster than `$.each`. You can see the source code for `each` at this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883691/1156119).
- **[-] reusable code (hardly, as commented above)**

  The main issue here is that your document ready is a whopping 85 lines long. You should be splitting it up into logical groupings and placing it in functions. This is something that a lot of new programmers have trouble with and I never really understood until I saw a great example. Consider a function of 85 lines of code vs:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      setupItemA();
      setupItemB();
      setupItemC();
      setupItemD();
  });
  ```

  This is much more readable, modular and reusable.
- **[+] clean code and good structure**

  This ties in a lot with above point 'reusable code' in my opinion. I'm assume your teacher was marking this point on consistency, indentation, appropriate calls, etc. which it seems to do pretty well.
- **[] Extra points for applied design pattern**

  This would depend on what design patterns you have been learning in your course.

### Code walkthrough

I'll now go through my implementation, line-by-line.

```
// Ideally this should go in your HTML page, I assume it wasn't an option though.
$("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />").insertAfter("[type='text/css']");   // CSS de Jquery UI

// This regex wouldn't be acceptable in a lot of companies as it's huge and difficult
// to read. A link to the source would be good in this situation.
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

// If your spacing is more consistent, your code will look cleaner. More than one 
// line in a row can make code look messy.

function setTabOn(stepNumber) {
    // This conversion is redundant, you're converting an int to an int and then using
    // it in a string. JavaScript does conversions like this implicitly anyhow
    //stepNumber = parseInt(stepNumber);

    // Caching
    var tab = $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab");
    tab.addClass("on");
    tab.click(function() {
        $(".step").hide();
        $("#step" + stepNumber).show();
        $("#steps a.active").removeClass("active");
    }); 
}

function nextStep(stepNumber) {
    stepNumber = parseInt(stepNumber) + 1;
    $(".step").hide();
    // You don't need to include the ol in 'ol#steps', it makes your code more specific
    // and thus less reusable.
    $("#steps li a").removeClass("active");
    $("#step" + stepNumber).show();
    $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").addClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your indentation went a little funny in your document ready

    $(".back").click(backClick);
    $("#step2_confirm_button").click(step2Confirm);
    $("#step2_cancel_button").click(step2Cancel);
    $("#step1_next").click(step1NextClick);
    $("#step2_next").click(step2NextClick);

    // Shuffled around in better order
    $(".step").hide();
    $("#step1").show();
    $("#step1_tab").addClass("active");
    $("#step2_confirm").hide();
});

function step2Confirm() {
    $("#step2_confirm").dialog("destroy");
    nextStep(2);
    setTabOn(2);
}

function step2Cancel() {
    $("#step2_confirm").dialog("destroy");
}

function backClick = function() {
    // You defined idBank twice here?
    //var idBack = $(this).attr("id");
    //var idBack = idBack.match(/\d/) - 1;
    // Use this.id instead of the jQuery alternative, it's much faster
    var idBack = this.id
    // I'm not sure what your regex was trying to do
    $(".step").hide();
    $("#step" + idBack).show(); 
};

function step1NextClick() { 
    var flagFirstStepError = 0;
    var flagFirstStepEmpty = 0;
    var flagFirstStepEmail = 0;

    $("#step1_errors").html("");

    var required = $(".required");
    for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            flagFirstStepError = 1;
            // Missing semi-colon
            return false;
        // Place } else { all on same line
        } else {
            flagFirstStepEmpty = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flagFirstStepError == 1) {
        showError(this, required);
    }

    var userEmail = $("#email").val();
    if (!isValidEmailAddress(userEmail)) {
        // Include a closing tag, address spelt wrong ;)
        $("#step1_errors").append("<p>You must provide a valid email address</p>");
        flagFirstStepEmail = 0;
    } else {
        flagFirstStepEmail = 1;
    }

    // Never do an operation of the left-hand side of an if
    if (flagFirstStepEmail  == 1 && flagFirstStepEmail == 1) {
        nextStep(1);
        setTabOn(1);
    }
}

function showError(sender, required) {
    // Only append the string once, keep in a variable
    var message = "We are sorry, but you need to enter all the required fields in order to proceed. The following information is missing: <br /><ol>";
    for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {                                                      
        if ($(sender).val() == "") {
            var y = $("#step1 label[for=" + sender.id + "]").html();
            message += "<li>You must fill the " + y + " field</li>";
        }
    }
    message += "</ol>";
    $("#step1_errors").append(message);
}

// I moved your events down here to reduce indentation, the size of document ready, and
// improve readability
function step2NextClick() { 
    $("#confirm_list li").remove();
    $("#share_list li label").find("input:checked").each(function() {   
        var x = $(this).val();                                                                                                          
        $("#confirm_list").append("<li>" + x + "</li>");
    });
    $("#step2_confirm").dialog();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**[-] caching (no jquery selector is cached)----**
**Your code**:

```
$("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").addClass("on");
$("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab").click(function() { ...
```

**Revised**:

```
var stepTab = $("#step" + stepNumber + "_tab");
stepTab.addClass("on");
stepTab.click(function() { ...
```

Storing the results of a selector will make sure you don't have to search the DOM for the "#step" + stepNumber + "_tab" element each time.

**[-] performance optimization (nope, usage of jquery each instead of a native loop)---**
**Original**:

```
$(".required").each(function() {    
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        flagFirstStepError = 1;
        return false
    }
    else {
        flagFirstStepEmpty = 1;
    }

});
```

**Revised**:

```
var requiredElems = $(".required"), length = requireElems.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    var requiredElem = $(requiredElems[i]);   
    if (requiredElem.val() == "") {
        flagFirstStepError = 1;
        return false
    }
    else {
        flagFirstStepEmpty = 1;
    }
}
```

The performance can be significantly slower using $.each because it needs to create a function and scope for each iteration where as the generic for loop has a lot less overhead and should be used in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimized version that I just made, if someone finds it useful

```
window.userProgress = 0;
var stepContent;
var stepTab;    
var backButtons;
var nextButtons;
var step2Confirm;

// CSS of Jquery UI
$("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />").insertAfter("[type='text/css']");   

// Email validation
function isValidEmailAddress(stepErrors) {
    var userEmail = $("#email").val();
    var flagStepEmail = 0;

    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

    if (!pattern.test(userEmail)) {
        var message = "<p> You must provide a valid email address</p>"; 
        printStepMessages(message, stepErrors);
        flagStepEmail = 1;
    }    
    return flagStepEmail;
};

// Set into the variable "userProgress" the reached step by the user
function changeUserProgress(button) {
    userProgress = parseInt(button.id.match(/\d/)) + 1;
}

// Checks whether the user is allowed to move further
function checkUserPermision(stepNumber) {
    if (isNaN(stepNumber)) {
        stepNumber = parseInt(stepNumber.id.match(/\d/)) + 1;
    }
    if (stepNumber <= userProgress ) {
        userMovement(stepNumber);
    }
}

// Hides and shows step content
function userMovement(stepNumber) {
    var contentToShow;
    changeTab(stepNumber);
    stepContent.hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < stepContent.length; i++) {
        contentToShow = stepContent[i];
        if(contentToShow.id == "step" + stepNumber) {
            contentToShow.style.display='block';    
        }
        }
}

// Sets the "active" and "on" classes on tabs
function changeTab(stepNumber) {
    var stepTabNumber;
    stepTab.removeClass("active");
    stepTab.removeClass("on");
    for (var i = 0; i < stepTab.length; i++) {
  var stepTabNumber = stepTab[i];
    var stepTabNumberId =  stepTabNumber.id.match(/\d/);
    if(stepTabNumberId == stepNumber) {
        stepTabNumber = $(stepTabNumber);
        stepTabNumber.addClass("active");   
    }
    else if(stepTabNumberId <= userProgress) {
        stepTabNumber = $(stepTabNumber);
        stepTabNumber.addClass("on");   
    }
    }   
}

// Shows messages to the user
function printStepMessages(message, stepMessageContainer, messageIntro, requiredElements) {
    if(messageIntro === undefined) {
      messageIntro = '';
  }
    if(requiredElements === undefined) {
    requiredElements = '';
  }
    stepMessageContainer.prepend(messageIntro);
    stepMessageContainer.append(message);
}       

// Checks if the required fields in Step 1 are filled and sets warning messages if not
function firstTabCheck(requiredFirstStepElements, step1Errors) {
    var message = "";
    var fieldElement;
    var firstStepEmpty = 0;
    var messageIntro = "We are sorry, but you need to enter all the required fields in order to proceed. The following information is missing: <br /><ol>";
    for (var i = 0; i < requiredFirstStepElements.length; i++) {
        var requiredFirstStepElement = requiredFirstStepElements[i];
        if (requiredFirstStepElement.value == "") {
            fieldElement = $("#step1 label[for=" + requiredFirstStepElement.id + "]").html();
            message += "<li>You must fill the " + fieldElement + " field</li>";
            firstStepEmpty += 1;
        }
    }
    message += "</ol>";
    if (firstStepEmpty > 0) {
        printStepMessages(message, step1Errors, messageIntro, requiredFirstStepElements);
    }   
    return firstStepEmpty;
}

// Sets message of confirmation for social networks 
function secondTabCheck(shareListLabel, socialConfirmList) {
    messaje = "<li>" + shareListLabel + "</li>";
    printStepMessages(messaje, socialConfirmList);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    stepContent = $(".step");
    stepTab = $("#steps").find("a");    
    backButtons = $(".back");
    nextButtons = $(".next");
    step2Confirm = $("#content #step2_confirm");
    var requiredFirstStepElements = $(".required"); 
    var socialConfirmList = $("#confirm_list");
    var step1Errors = $("#step1_errors");
    var shareListLabels = $("#share_list li label");

    stepContent.hide();
    step2Confirm.hide();
    $("#content #step1").show();
    $("#content #step1_tab").addClass("active");

    $("#step1_next").click(function() { 
        step1Errors.html("");
        var firstStepEmpty = firstTabCheck(requiredFirstStepElements, step1Errors);
        var firstStepEmail = isValidEmailAddress(step1Errors);
        if (firstStepEmpty == 0 && firstStepEmail  == 0) {
        changeUserProgress(this);
        }
    }); 

    $("#step2_next").click(function() {
        var shareListLabel;
        if(userProgress < 3) {                                                                  
            $("#confirm_list li").remove();
            var shareListLabelsCheck = shareListLabels.find("input:checked");   
            for (var i = 0; i < shareListLabelsCheck.length; i++) {     
                shareListLabel = $(shareListLabelsCheck[i]).val();
                secondTabCheck(shareListLabel, socialConfirmList);
            }       
            if(socialConfirmList.children().length > 0) {
                step2Confirm.dialog();
            }
            else {
                changeUserProgress(this);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#step2_confirm_button").click(function() {
        step2Confirm.dialog("destroy");
        changeUserProgress(this);
        checkUserPermision(this);
    });

    $("#step2_cancel_button").click(function() {
        step2Confirm.dialog("destroy");
    });

    stepTab.click(function() {                                           
        var idElement = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d/));  
        checkUserPermision(idElement);
    });

    nextButtons.click(function() {                                           
        var idElement = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d/)) + 1;  
        checkUserPermision(idElement);
    });

    backButtons.click(function() {
        var idElement = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d/)) - 1;
        userMovement(idElement);
    });

});
```